# How to tell solid vs. non-solid electrolytic capacitor?

Tags: capacitor, electrolytic-capacitor

Datasheet of these capacitors (Panasonic FK series -- surface mount) does not say anything about it (https://industrial.panasonic.com/cdbs/www-data/pdf/RDE0000/ABA0000C1181.pdf).  For reliability assessment, I need to know whether they are solid or non-solid electrolyte.

Is there some way to tell, either from the parameters, shape/look, etc.?

I know I can ask Panasonic, but my experience (with manufacturers in general, not necessarily Panasonic specifically) is that *in the best case*, it will take ages to get an answer from them.

Comment: Would you like to share the link to the datasheet with us?

Comment: Does it have a breather hole?

Comment: @brhans -- I edited the post to include the link

Comment: @Andyaka -- I don't have one with me, but I can ask some of my colleagues to check.  Can you specify what the rule is?  (does breather hole mean solid, or non-solid?)

Comment: Has to be standard al elect based on name and impedance ratio from cold to room temp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Panasonic calls their solid-electrolyte capacitors ["Conductive Polymer Electrolytic"](https://industrial.panasonic.com/ww/products/capacitors/polymer-capacitors). All "Aluminum Electrolytic" as well as "Conductive Polymer Hybrid Aluminum Electrolytic" capacitors contain liquid electrolyte.

Answer (score 1):

Page one of the datasheet mentions a 'pressure relief' in the 'dimensions' section. So my guess is it's a liquid electrolyte.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Solid and Non-solid electrolytic capacitors can be differentiated with there shapes (by looking at images in datasheets). Shared below is the link that describes the shapes.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aluminum_electrolytic_capacitor

Look at the "Polarity Marking" section, under "Additional Information" block that is written at the last few pages in the above link.

Note:
Aluminum electrolytic capacitors with non-solid electrolyte have a polarity marking at the cathode (minus) side.
Aluminum electrolytic capacitors with solid electrolyte have a polarity marking at the anode (plus) side.